# HTML + Javascript: Dynamic Image Resize?

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize-image

I am trying to get some `JavaScript` to programmatically adjust a HTML `img` tag's width to display various sized images correctly.

I have a fixed width `img` tag at `800px` to display an image, this is the max width.

If the image is wider then `800px` I want to display it at `800px` wide;

If the image is less than `800px` wide I want to preserve its width to avoid stretching it.

I use this html/javacript code to get a partial solution:

```js
function resize_image(id) {
 var img = document.getElementById(id);
 var normal_width = img.width;
 img.removeAttribute("width");
 var real_width = img.width;
 if (real_width < normal_width) {
  img.width = real_width;
 } else {
  img.width = normal_width;
 }
}
```

```html
<img id="myimage" onload="resize_image(self.id);" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" width="800" />
```

The above code seems to work on all browsers I have tested except `Safari` (images don't display unless you refresh the page).

I know I can use CSS `max-width` but that wont work on `IE` < 7 which is a show stopper.

How can I get this working for all browsers? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never seen a safari in work, but you can try changing your onload event to this:

```
onload="resize_image(self.id);return true"
```

It could be that without a return value, safari thinks that this object should not be loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Use the IE6 css+javascript hack:

```
.dynamic_img {
    width: expression(document.body.clientWidth <= 800? "auto" : "800px");
    max-width: 800px; //For normal browsers
}
```

Comment: This has a performance cost, so you can't have a bunch of them on the page.

Comment: Hm, I've just tested it and guess what, that expression is evaluated on any possible event. And I was naive to think it evaluates only once...

Answer (score 1):

Without id:

```
...
  function resize_image( img )
  {
     //var img = document.getElementById( id );
...
  <img onload="resize_image(this);" src="IMAGE.JPG" width="800" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried monkey with `img.style.width`? You could also try having 2 CSS classes for each of the 2 conditions and programmaticly change them.